# Javascript - Variable Missing

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am having some issues getting this javascript and css to work correctly on about 50% of machines. The odd things is, they're all work computers that have browsers up-to-date and I have tried multiple browsers. I can verify that this code works correctly, but can't verify why it's not working on a large amount of machines. Here is my beginning code with js:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<style type='text/css'>
.body-content {
    background: rgba(255, 202, 25);
    color: red;
    position: relative;
    left: 20em;
    top: -6.2em;
    background-color: rgb(255, 202, 25);
    padding: 10px 100px;
    font-weight: 700;
    line-height: 2em;
    max-width: 45em;
    border: 3px solid yellow;
    border-radius: 7px;
}

.comp-form {
    color: rgb(24, 33, 128);
    transform: rotate(90deg);
    font-family: Trebuchet MS, Lucida Grande, Lucida Sans Unicode, Lucida Sans, Tahoma, sans-serif;
    font-size: 70px;
    transform-origin: 5%;
    font-style: normal;
    font-variant: small-caps;
    text-shadow: yellow 0px 0px 10px, yellow 0px 0px 10px, yellow 0px 0px 10px, yellow 0px 0px 10px, yellow 0px 0px 10px, yellow 0px 0px 10px;
    font-weight: 700;
    line-height: 2em;
    position: absolute;
    border: 3px solid black;
    background: rgb(255, 202, 25);
    padding: 0 600px;
    z-index: 1;
    left: -20px;
    top: -400px;
}

.country-select {
    position: absolute;
    top: 58px;
    left: 325px;
    color: yellow;
}

body {
  background-color: rgb(24, 33, 128);
  position: relative;
  top: 6.5em;
  font-color: white;
}

.submitbutton {
    -moz-box-shadow:inset 50px 50px 50px 0px #ffc919;
    -webkit-box-shadow:inset 50px 50px 50px 0px #ffc919;
    box-shadow:inset 50px 50px 50px 0px yellow;
    background:-webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #ffc919), color-stop(1, #ffc919) );
    background:-moz-linear-gradient( center top, #ffc919 5%, #ffc919 100% );
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ffc919', endColorstr='#ffc919');
    background-color:#ffc919;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius:37px;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft:37px;
    border-top-left-radius:37px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius:0px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright:0px;
    border-top-right-radius:0px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius:37px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright:37px;
    border-bottom-right-radius:37px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius:0px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft:0px;
    border-bottom-left-radius:0px;
    text-indent:0px;
    border:9px solid #182180;
    display:inline-block;
    color:#182180;
    font-family:Comic Sans MS;
    font-size:33px;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-style:normal;
    height:63px;
    line-height:40px;
    width:147px;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-align:center;
    position: relative;
    left: -120px;
    bottom: 25px;
    text-shadow: yellow 0px 0px 10px, yellow 0px 0px 10px, yellow 0px 0px 10px, yellow 0px 0px 10px, yellow 0px 0px 10px, yellow 0px 0px 10px;
    border-shadow: yellow 0px 0px 10px, yellow 0px 0px 10px, yellow 0px 0px 10px, yellow 0px 0px 10px, yellow 0px 0px 10px, yellow 0px 0px 10px;
}

.submitbutton:active {
    position: relative;
    top:-20px;
    color: yellow;
    border-color: yellow;
    box-shadow:inset 50px 50px 50px 0px rgb(24, 33, 128);
}

.cancelbutton {
    -moz-box-shadow:inset 50px 50px 50px 0px #ffc919;
    -webkit-box-shadow:inset 50px 50px 50px 0px #ffc919;
    box-shadow:inset 50px 50px 50px 0px yellow;
    background:-webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #ffc919), color-stop(1, #ffc919) );
    background:-moz-linear-gradient( center top, #ffc919 5%, #ffc919 100% );
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ffc919', endColorstr='#ffc919');
    background-color:#ffc919;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius:0px;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft:0px;
    border-top-left-radius:0px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius:37px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright:37px;
    border-top-right-radius:37px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius:0px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright:0px;
    border-bottom-right-radius:0px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius:37px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft:37px;
    border-bottom-left-radius:37px;
    text-indent:0px;
    border:9px solid #182180;
    display:inline-block;
    color:#182180;
    font-family:Comic Sans MS;
    font-size:33px;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-style:normal;
    height:63px;
    line-height:40px;
    width:147px;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-align:center;
    position: relative;
    left: -120px;
    bottom: 25px;
    text-shadow: yellow 0px 0px 10px, yellow 0px 0px 10px, yellow 0px 0px 10px, yellow 0px 0px 10px, yellow 0px 0px 10px, yellow 0px 0px 10px;
    border-shadow: yellow 0px 0px 10px, yellow 0px 0px 10px, yellow 0px 0px 10px, yellow 0px 0px 10px, yellow 0px 0px 10px, yellow 0px 0px 10px;
}

.cancelbutton:active {
    position: relative;
    top:-20px;
    color: yellow;
    border-color: yellow;
    box-shadow:inset 50px 50px 50px 0px rgb(24, 33, 128);
}

.ccTitle {
    color: rgb(24, 33, 128);
    font-family: Trebuchet MS, Lucida Grande, Lucida Sans Unicode, Lucida Sans, Tahoma, sans-serif;
    font-size: 70px;
    font-style: normal;
    font-variant: small-caps;
    text-shadow: yellow 0px 0px 10px, yellow 0px 0px 10px, yellow 0px 0px 10px, yellow 0px 0px 10px, yellow 0px 0px 10px, yellow 0px 0px 10px;
    font-weight: 700;
    line-height: 2em;
    position: relative;
    left: 250px;
    border: 3px solid black;
    background: rgb(255, 202, 25);
    width: 80%;
    top: -170px;
    padding: 0 100px;
    z-index: 2;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.dropbox1 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 4.45em;
    left: 34.5em;
}

.dropbox2 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 3.75em;
    left: 36em;
    color: yellow;
}

.expimg {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    float: left;
    position: absolute;
    left: -15px;
    top: -170px;
    border: 3px solid black;
    z-index: 3;
}

.tableheader {
    color: rgb(24, 33, 128);
    font-family: Trebuchet MS, Lucida Grande, Lucida Sans Unicode, Lucida Sans, Tahoma, sans-serif;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-style: normal;
    font-variant: small-caps;
    text-shadow: yellow 0px 0px 10px, yellow 0px 0px 10px, yellow 0px 0px 10px, yellow 0px 0px 10px, yellow 0px 0px 10px, yellow 0px 0px 10px;
    font-weight: 700;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}

#reqTbl {
    position: relative;
    top: 20px;
    left: -28px;
    padding: 30px;
    border: 3px solid yellow;
    border-radius: 7px;
    width: 760px
}

#supplierTbl {
    position: relative;
    top: 50px;
    left: -30px;
    padding: 30px;
    border: 3px solid yellow;
    border-radius: 7px;
}

#currencyTbl {
    position: relative;
    top: -170px;
    left: 357px;
    border: 3px solid yellow;
    padding: 30px 30px;
    border-radius: 7px;
    width: 375px;
}

tr {
    color: rgb(24, 33, 128);
    font-size: 14px;
    text-align: center;
}

#commentsheader {
    position: relative;
    top: -100px;
    left: -33px;
    padding: 30px;
    border: 3px solid yellow;
    border-radius: 7px;
    width: 460px;
}

#commentBox {
    position: relative;
    top: -127px;
    left: -33px;
    padding: 30px;
    border: 3px solid yellow;
    border-radius: 7px;
    height: 200px;
    width: 700px;
}

#MPIFid {
    position: relative;
    bottom: 0px;
    right: 290px;
    overflow: auto;
}
</style>
</head>
```

And the HTML (I have functions that are not built yet in this. Please let me know if this could be an issue):

```
    <body>
<h1 class="ccTitle">CURRENCY CONVERSIONS</h1>
<h2 class="comp-form">Header2</h2>
<img src="http:/photo.png" alt="Logo" class="expimg">
<div class="country-select">Select Bank Country:</div>
        <select name="slist1" class="dropbox1" onchange="SList.getSelect('slist2', this.value);">
            <option>- - -</option>
            <option value="United_States">United States</option>
            <option value="Italy">Italy</option>
            <option value="Greece">Greece</option>
        </select>
<span id="slist2" class="dropbox2"></span>
<div id="test" style="display:none;" class="body-content">
    <form id='curForm'>
        <table id='reqTbl'>
            <tr>
                <th class='tableheader' align='center' colspan=3>Prerequisites</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Has the partner already been placed on stop sell?
                </td>
                <td>
                    <label for="Yes"><input type="radio" name='Stop Sell' value="Yes" id='ssYes' onmouseover="tooltip.show('The supplier must be placed on Stop Sell prior to the request being submitted/processed.', 200);" onmouseout="tooltip.hide();">Yes</label>
                    <label for="No"><input type="radio" name='Stop Sell' value="No" id='ssNo' onmouseover="tooltip.show('The supplier must be placed on Stop Sell prior to the request being submitted/processed.', 200);" onmouseout="tooltip.hide();">No</label>
                </td>
            </tr>  
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Has the Market Manager given approval for this conversion?
                </td>
                <td>
                    <label for="Yes"><input type="radio" name='Market Manager Approval' value="Yes" id='mmApproved' onmouseover="tooltip.show('Approval from the Market Manager associated with the supplier is required before any requests can be submitted/processed.', 200);" onmouseout='tooltip.hide();'>Yes</label>
                    <label for="No"><input type="radio" name='Market Manager Approval' value="No" id='mmDenied' onmouseover="tooltip.show('Approval from the Market Manager associated with the supplier is required before any requests can be submitted/processed.', 200);" onmouseout='tooltip.hide();\'>No</label>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Market Manager that supplied approval
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="Market Manager Name" id='mmName' onmouseover="tooltip.show('Name of Market Manager who has approved the request',200);" onmouseout="tooltip.hide();" onfocus='this.value=fieldFocus(this);' onblur='this.value=asteriskize(this);'>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Effective Date of Currency Change
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" size="10" name="Effective Date of Currency Change" id="dateBox" onblur="this.value=asteriskize(this);" onmouseover="tooltip.show('Please click to select the date from which this change should be effective.', 200);" onmouseout="tooltip.hide();"
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <table id="supplierTbl">
            <tr>
                <th class='tableheader' align='center' colspan=3>Partner Info</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Vendor ID
                </td>
                <td>
                    ID
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type='text' name='AccountingVendorID' id='accountingVendorID' onfocus='this.value=fieldFocus(this);' onblur='this.value=asteriskize(this);' onmouseover="tooltip.show('Vendor ID of supplier.', 200);" onmouseout="tooltip.hide();" onkeypress="return valNum(event);">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type='text' name='SampleID1' id='SampeID2' onfocus='this.value=fieldFocus(this);' onblur='this.value=asteriskize(this);' onmouseover="tooltip.show('Also referred to as the EID.', 200);" onmouseout="tooltip.hide();" onkeypress="return valNum(event);">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Partner Name
                </td>
                <td>
                    Country
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type='text' name='Supplier Name' id='supplierName' onfocus='this.value=fieldFocus(this);' onblur='this.value=asteriskize(this);' onmouseover="tooltip.show('Name of the supplier.', 200);" onmouseout="tooltip.hide();">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type='text' name='City Name' id='cityName' onfocus='this.value=fieldFocus(this);' onblur='this.value=asteriskize(this);' onmouseover="tooltip.show('City in which the supplier is located.', 200);" onmouseout="tooltip.hide();">
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <table id='currencyTbl'>
            <tr>
                <th class='tableheader' align='center' colspan=3>Currency</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Current Currency:
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="Current PeopleSoft Currency" id='currentCurr' onmouseover="tooltip.show('Current Currency',200);" onmouseout="tooltip.hide();" onfocus='this.value=fieldFocus(this);' onblur='this.value=asteriskize(this);'>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Desired Currency:
                </td>
                <td>
                    <select name='Desired Currency' id='desiredCurr' onmouseover="tooltip.show('New Currency', 200);" onmouseout="tooltip.hide();">
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th  class='tableheader' id='commentsheader'>Comments</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td  style='height:308px;width:500px;'>
                    <textarea id='commentBox'></textarea>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <table id="MPIFid">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div id="scontent" class="body-content"></div>
                <td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td width='920px'>
                    <button type='button' id='submitButtonid' class='submitbutton' onclick='sendItOff();'>Submit</button>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <button type='button' id='cancelButtonid' class='cancelbutton' onclick='confirmCancel();'>Cancel</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</div>
```

Here's the Javascript:

```
<script language='javascript'> 

    var SList = new Object(); // JS object declaration that stores data for options
    var txtsl2 = 'Select Payment Method (If EFT, select MPIF Country/Language combination): ';

    /*
    Information that populates in dropbox 2 from the dropbox 1.
    Could be potential spot for Basecamp function call once created.
    */

    SList.slist2 = {
      "United_States": ['Card', 'EFT - US/English'],
      "Italy": ['Card', 'EFT - IT/English','EFT - IT/Italian'],
      "Greece": ['Card', 'EFT - GR/English', 'EFT - GR/Greek']
    };

    /*
     Object that stores content after 2nd dropbox selection.
    */

    SList.scontent = {
      "EFT - US/English": '**Please have the partner submit a form through the following link**: LINK',
      "EFT - IT/Italian": '**Please have the partner submit an MPIF form through the following link**: LINK',
      "EFT - IT/English": '**Please have the partner submit an MPIF form through the following link**: LINK',
      "EFT - GR/English": '**Please have the partner submit an MPIF form through the following link**: LINK',
      "EFT - GR/Greek": '**Please have the partner submit an MPIF form through the following link**: LINK',
    };

/* DO NOT TOUCH BELOW */

// function to get the dropdown list, or content
SList.getSelect = function(slist, option) {
document.getElementById('scontent').innerHTML = ''; // empty option-content
    if (SList[slist][option]) {
        // if option from the last Select, add text-content, else, set dropdown list
        if (slist === 'scontent') document.getElementById('scontent').innerHTML = SList[slist][option];
        else if (slist === 'slist2') {
            var addata = '<option>- - -</option>';
            for (var i = 0; i < SList[slist][option].length; i++) {
                addata += '<option value="' + SList[slist][option][i] + '">' + SList[slist][option][i] + '</option>';
            }
        document.getElementById('slist2').innerHTML = txtsl2 + '<select name="slist2" onchange="SList.getSelect(\'scontent\', this.value); check_dd();">' + addata + '></select>';
        }
    } else if (slist === 'slist2') {
        // empty the tag for 2n
        document.getElementById('slist2').innerHTML = '';
    }
};

// drops the form data down after 2nd selection
function check_dd() {
    if(document.getElementById('slist2').value === "- - -") {
        document.getElementById('test').style.display = 'none';
    } else {
        document.getElementById('test').style.display = 'block';
    };
};
</script>
</html>
```

There are 3 things that could potentially happen with what I've found.

1) The page as it is right now will work flawlessly.
2) The page will have some CSS issues, but the javascript will still work.
3) The page will not function at all.

When the page will not function at all, the console in Chrome shows the error `Error: Uncaught ReferenceError: SList is not definedListPicker._handleMouseUp @ about:blank:510`

As you can see, ListPicker is NOT anywhere in my code. I'm thoroughly confused.

Please help!! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After testing your code, I can only conclude that your problems do not stem from erroneous JavaScript, but rather poorly written markup. Some browsers are pretty good at piecing together bad HTML, but others may not be.

I would recommend you clean up and format your HTML. Make sure all of your tags are properly closed (and in some cases, opened) and that you don't nest too many quotes.

Also, the error you mention at the end of your question simply states that the `SList` variable was referenced before it had been defined. Putting your JavaScript at the bottom of your `<body>` tag might fix this.

Comment: Do you have any software suggestions to cleanup this markup and all of my syntax for javascript? I have notepad++ and NetBeans, but it's not exactly what I'm looking for in writing this stuff. I also need to reorganize the table to make the css easier. Finding software that can show me what it looks like would be beneficial.....

Comment: @Hatchet I went through and cleaned the code up majorly. The js code doesn't work in JS fiddle: [link](https://jsfiddle.net/LyL2vdn4/2/embedded/result/)

Comment: @Eric in jsfiddle, change the location of the JavaScript to in the <head> tag.

Comment: @Hatchet Nice, you're awesome... I got it working on jsfiddle whether it was in the head or the body. I just need a little bit more work on it. I'll test it out tomorrow when I have access to where I'm going to put it and report my findings. I appreciate it a lot. If I could give you a vote up, I would.

Comment: @Eric Glad I could help! If you want, you can mark my answer as accepted (click the check mark to the left of my answer). Thanks!

Comment: @Hatchet - Okay, I cleaned up the markup and changed the code in the question area with the cleaned up version. It looks like this code now works effectively with some css issues in chrome once I upload it. This code is still not working in IE. The CSS in IE looks like it would if you clicked "Normalized CSS" in jsfiddle and the javascript does not function. Any ideas? Please note that the code is in the exact order that I've listed above. Could the javascript be moved to the top of the body to correct this issue you think? I'm not sure the "Transform" property in CSS is working in IE either.

Comment: @Eric what does your console say? (f12) you can play around a lot in there to fix your HTML. You can change CSS rules, alter your HTML see what CSS rules are invalid or are not being used. You have posted a lot of code

Comment: @Adjit The error I'm getting is `SCRIPT5009: 'SList' is undefined 
change.HTML, line 274 character 1` It's not finding the SList variable for some reason. I was thinking it's location of the variable. The issue is here `<select name="slist1" class="dropbox1" onchange="SList.getSelect('slist2', this.value);">` it doesn't see `var SList = new Object(); // JS object declaration that stores data for options`

Comment: @Eric Is that in IE? Sorry, but I'm on Linux, so I might not be able to help you much there.

Comment: @eric try changing your onchange to `onchange="javascript:blablbabla"`

Comment: @Adjit `onchange` shouldn't need to be prefixed with `javascript:`; that's for links.

Comment: @Adjit I changed the onchange to `<select name="slist1" class="dropbox1" onchange="javascript:SList.getSelect('slist2', this.value);">` and it's still throwing the same error.

Comment: @Hatchet Yes it's in IE. I would just use Chrome, but the company I work for is worldwide and I have to make sure it works in all browsers.... shoot me! :/

Comment: @Eric Are your problems only in IE now?

Comment: @Hatchet Yep, that's correct. Thank you! I've verified this on about 5 machines that's it working in Chrome. Thank you for that. The Browser is definitely the common denominator at this point.

Comment: @Eric I have a Windows VM with IE that I can use... Give me a minute.

Comment: @Hatchet It works in IE when you put it in JSfiddle. It works when you open the .html file in IE as well. When I actually put the file on my companies intranet to host it, it doesn't work in IE, but does in Chrome. I'm going to download the most recent IE on another machine and see if it'll work when I open it from our intranet.

Comment: @Hatchet MY IE version is updated to 11.0.9600.17843CO and it still doesn't work. I know nothing about metas, extensions, or any of that business. Could that be the problem?

Comment: I'm only testing on the fiddle, and it works on my IE. You have the (unworking) live version, and if the code is identical, I don't know what's up. I don't have enough experience with IE-specific problems to authoritatively tell you what to do. The only thing I can think of that might help would be refactoring your code to use JS's `addEventListener` method instead of HTML's `onXYZ` attributes.